# Focus state on before element

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have a simple input element in HTML which prepends `$` to the input, this is so it doesn't get contained as part of the input value. To achieve this I'm using CSS as you can see in the example below.

The problem I'm having is that the focus state on the input isn't working for the `:before` element which prepends the `$`, which isn't great for accessibility reasons. Is there a way to do this with pure CSS so when the input is focused it makes the `$` change color too?

```css
input {
  margin: 3em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

input:focus {
  color: green;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #dedede;
  display: inline;
}

.test:before {
  content: '$';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) helps here, if supported.

Comment: Just to make user: do you want the $ to appear before the input *field* or before the input field's *content*? Also: which accessibility issue are you trying to solve? Should solutions be fully accessible?

Comment: Before the content.

Comment: If accessibility is a concern, I would also recommend adding a `title` that explains that $ should not be entered in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1

You can use the [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) feature here. But the `:focus-within` does not support IE.

[See browser support list.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within#Browser_compatibility)

### Method 2

```css
.test input {
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.test input:focus,
.test input:focus + label {
  color: green;
}

.test label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #dedede;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <input id="input" type="text"/>
  <label for="input">$</label>
</div>
```

### Method 3

When you need work on the ":before" selector;

```css
.test input {
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.test input:focus,
.test input:focus + label {
  color: green;
}

.test label:before {
  display: block;
  content: '$';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #dedede;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <input id="input" type="text"/>
  <label for="input"></label>
</div>
```